# Desktop won't boot with external hard drive plugged in

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell, bios, external-hdd

So, I'm building an arcade machine and I'm using a Dell Inspiron 530 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have an external hard drive that needs to stay plugged in at all times as I'd prefer not to have to plug it in every time I boot up the machine (the desktop's located in a place that makes it difficult to get to every time I need to turn it on).

Whenever the external drive is plugged in, I can't get beyond the Dell BIOS splash screen, and can't enter Setup or One-Time Boot Menu. The PC just freezes up, so there's not a way for me to adjust the boot order of the internal hard drives and any external ones.

I know my BIOS are also out of date (it currently is running BIOS Revision 1.0.16), but I can't seem to figure out a way to update the BIOS if I'm running Ubuntu.

1. Is there anything I can do to keep the external drive plugged in and still boot up properly?
2. How can I update my BIOS (if that's the issue) if I'm running Ubuntu on my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

One of the partitions on your external drive has the "Boot" flag set. Your BIOS finds this partition first, and tries to boot from it. Since there's no bootable code on that partition, it fails.

Read `man parted`, `umount` the drive, and use  `parted`'s `set` subcommand to clear the "boot" flag.

Be Very Sure you're "fixing" the right disk. If you clear the "boot" flag on the wrong disk's partition, your system won't boot.

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: I removed the boot flag, but the machine still won't boot up without the external drive unplugged. The only other flag listed is the msftdata one